# Excel - creating csv file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to enter the data manually in a excel file and generate the below CSV File format. 
Problem is I entered the data in 11 rows(Excel).  First row has 10 columns. Second row has 15 columns. Last row has 4 columns.  Some columns can have empty data also.  When i save the file as csv file first line and last line has 15 columns.  How can i generated the csv file. what i need to do to include the empty columns in the csv file

H,TEST_w99999999999_f101203001,03/12/2010,02:45:28,MIS,MISC,MIS,NEW,,
D,,0027940622,,,MISC,030100059566901-000000452312108,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,57.25,,
D,,0027940622,,,MISC,030100059566901-000000452312109,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,56.00,,
D,,2000003318,,,MISC,030200059566901-000000452308586,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,0.92,,
D,,2000004473,,,MISC,030300059566901-000000452176305,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,-0.45,,
D,,2000004439,,,MISC,030300059566901-000000452243016,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,-38.28,,
D,,2000003460,,,MISC,030300059566901-000000452251974,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,-267.77,,
D,,2000006846,,,MISC,030300059566901-000000452300634,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,-0.05,,
D,,2000006846,,,MISC,030300059566901-000000452300636,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,0.05,,
D,,2000004059,,,MISC,030300059576013-000000452317628,MIS,03/12/2010,,,1,272.50,,
T,TEST_w99999999999_f101203001,9,80.17

Comment: can anyonepls  respond to my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Sub SaveAsCSV()
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
          "C:\NewCsvDile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
           CreateBackup:=False
   End Sub
```

Comment: Header and tail records have different number of columns. How can i resolve it.

Comment: Just save it as a "CSV (comma delimited) (*.csv)." type.  You'll only have as many columns per row as you have data.  Empty cells between columns will also be respected. Can you post a screenshot of the excel file you are filling?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  I am not sure how i can paste screen scot here. Only text box is available.

Comment: Nice to hear it helped.  To insert pictures in a post, use the 6th icon from the left.  The one that looks like a polaroid picture.